# Cloud9 IDE - Terminal shortcut to start rails server

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cloud9-ide

i'm new to development in general and I'm starting with rails.  I learned via the Hartl Rails Tutorial (and a few other resources) and am using cloud9 IDE.  I noticed that every time I want to launch the server in C9 i need to type the following:

```
rails s -b $IP -p $PORT
```

Is there a shortcut, hotkey, alias etc so I can simply type something like "rails s"?  Seems unnecessarily annoying to have to type that whole thing out every single time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you'll need to set a bash alias. To launch it with "launchRails" you'd add a line like this to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` files (either one will work):

```
alias railsAlias="rails s -b $IP -p $PORT"
```

You can open up those files with `c9 ~/.bashrc`.

For a multi-word alias like "rails command", you might consider a solution like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/105375/bash-spaces-in-alias-name).

---

Source: [How and where to set bash alias](https://community.c9.io/t/how-and-where-to-set-bash-alias/836)

Answer (score 1):

To use `railss` as an alias, run this in the Cloud9 terminal:

```
echo -e "\nalias railss='rails server -b \$IP -p \$PORT'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
```

This will append the `railss` alias to the end of the provided `~/.bash_aliases` file.

Open a new Terminal tab on Cloud9 and the `railss` alias should work in the new Terminal tab. From now on you can use `railss` instead of `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT`.

---

*At time of writing `~/.bash_aliases` is provided on Cloud9 by default. If you don't have the `~/.bash_aliases` file, use `~/.bashrc` instead.*

*Optional: to make the `railss` alias available in old, already-opened Terminal tabs, run `source ~/.bash_aliases`.*

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to **restart** your C9 IDE. Otherwise the .bash_aliases nor .bashrc won't be recognized as updated.